# Python 2.7 array range using larger integers doesn't work right

Tags: python, arrays, range

```
array = [2,3,2,4,7,9]  
for a in range(2,4):
    print a

2
3
```

This is what I want, a print of only numbers within a narrow range. But the numbers I need to use are much larger. And when I try the same thing with larger numbers I get a print of something else. For example:

```
array = [22,57,205,276,476]

for a in range(200,210):
    print a

200 201 202 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209
```

That's not what I want. I expected to get only 205. Apparently my use of larger numbers changed behavior of my program. How can I just get 205?

Thanks, Rico

Comment: You need to read the `range()` [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range). You clearly think it does something it does not.

Comment: Even without knowing what `range()` does, your code should raise some red flags. How does the for loop know what list it's supposed to be looking at? For it to do what you wanted it to do, you'd have to specify the `array` variable somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You are just printing all the values in those range, without comparing to the array elements. The first one worked was just a coincidence that you had both `2` and `3` in the array.

If you want to print array elements in certain range, then you have to do it with a loop:

```
rng = range(200, 210)

for elem in array:
    if elem in rng:
        print elem
```

or, with a list comprehension:

```
[elem for elem in array if elem in rng]
```

You can also avoid creating a new list of range. Just check bounds using comparison operators:

```
[elem for elem in array if 200 <= elem < 210]
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Thank you hcwhsa and Rohit, you guys are the best!

Comment: @Rico It is considered good practice to accept the answer that is most helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

`range()` returns a list(in py2.x) and you're iterating over that list and printing its items.

```
>>> range(2,4)
[2, 3]
>>> range(200,210)
[200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209]
```

Docs: [`for` Statements](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Perhaps you wanted to do this:

```
>>> array = [22,57,205,276,476]
# `item` is assigned the values from the list during loop.
>>> for item in array:  
...     if 200 <= item < 210: #Equivalent to `item >=200 and item <210`
...         print item
...         
205
```

And looking at your first example you may also want to use a `set` to keep a track of items already printed:

```
>>> array = [2,3,2,4,7,9]
>>> seen = set()
>>> for item in array:
...     if 2 <= item < 4 and item not in seen:
...         print item
...         seen.add(item)
...         
2
3
```